# stuck up installing object-detection-api

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm stuck up installing Object-Detection-API, the terminals show me this error, I followed TensorFlow documentation at: https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#general-remarks, I also upgraded pip and everything exactly like the documentation.

```
  WARNING: --use-feature=2020-resolver no longer has any effect, since it is now the 
    default dependency resolver in pip. This will become an error in pip 21.0.
    ERROR: You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the pip version mismatch, upgrade your pip version by using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and install your packages using `pip install <PACKAGE> --use-feature=2020-resolver`. For more details please refer to this [documentation](https://discuss.python.org/t/announcement-pip-20-2-release/4863). Thank You!